# Capture pasted text in GWT Textbox

Tags: java, gwt

I want to handle paste event and **catching pasted text** of a `TextBox` in GWT. As I checked there are no standard handlers for paste events in `TextBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out can do it with a little javascript native code added:

```
public class PasteAwareTextBox extends TextBox {

    public PasteAwareTextBox() {
        super();
        sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
        case Event.ONPASTE:
            onPasted(getClipboardData(event));
            break;
        }

    }

    private void onPasted(String clipboardData) {
        System.out.println("Pasted:" + clipboardData);
    }

    private static native String getClipboardData(Event event) /*-{
        return event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'); 
    }-*/;

}
```

1) Subscribing for paste events.

2) Call `event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');` through JSNI.